# Secure media file on Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, download, token, media

I have a Django site with many PDFs .backend serve to frontend with DRF(api),I use token authentication instead of session authentication ,I send token in header every request.I d like users have valid token can download media file how can I implement this?

Comment: put code of api view

Answer (score 0):

When i need to implement an endpoint returning a Media only for logged user i do something like this:

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=("get",))
    def pdf(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = self.get_object()
        response = HttpResponse(
            content=object.pdf.read(), content_type="application/pdf"
        )
        response[
            "Content-Disposition"
        ] = f"attachment; filename={os.path.basename(object.pdf.name)}"
        return response
```

I assume the pdfs are related/saved in a django model instances, if you want to share a static files stored in the backend the solution is slightly different:

```
class PDFView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pdf_name = kwargs["pdf_name"]
        with open(os.path.join(settings.PDF_DIR, pdf_name), "rb") as pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response["Content-Disposition"] = "inline;filename=%s" % pdf_name
            return response
```